# Nonsensical torch.nn.BCELoss RuntimeError: all elements of input should be between 0 and 1

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

I'm trying to train my pytorch NN module with `torch.nn.BCELoss`.

My code was already running, but some changes that I can't revert are now throwing me the following error

`RuntimeError: all elements of input should be between 0 and 1`. This happens when calling the loss function. However, all the elements of both inputs (the prediction and the ground truth) **are** between 0 and 1, as they're output from a Sigmoid!

I checked it by iterating over the tensors. Both tensors are also of the same shape and type (`<torch.Tensor>`) and size (`torch.Size([24375])`).

I tried exchanging the BCELoss for BCEWithLogitsLoss and omitting the output sigmoid. However, that is returning `nan` results for me at the moment.

If it's relevant, I'm currently working on CPU and not on cuda.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: it seems like your network diverged: you are getting `NaN`s that are outside `[0,1]` range, even with Sigmoid activation.

Comment: @Shai thanks. Any idea on how I could fix the divergence of the network? Would regularization, adding more/bigger hidden layers, or something else, help?
Just to add to this: When manually checking the outputs, I still don't find any values outside of [0,1] after the activation.

Answer (score 0):

There are possibly two main problems with this error.

1. Your input variables contain NaN.
2. Need normalisation of data.

The first reason is highly probable. If your input variables have NaN in them, then it's highly probable that you will have NaN as output from your network.